# How to tag and vpc custom resource lambda via serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless` to deploy lambda and APIGateway to AWS. I found serverless deploy a lambda with a random name during deployment automatically. It is to attach some role policy required for apigateway to call lambda. This lambda is not managed by me.

For example, when you deploy a lambda with http endpoint like below:

```
  handler: xxx
  events:
    - http:
        path: '/v1/order'
        method: 'post'
```

`serverless` will deploy a lambda with a auto generated name which attach a role on the apigateway to be able to invoke this lambda. I attached this lambda source code at the bottom. The lambda tag `aws:cloudformation:stack-name` is in the same stack as the other resources in the same serverless.yml.

What I am looking for is how to add tags on those auto generated lambda. And how to attach VPC on those lambdas?

I have tried to put tags and vpc under `provider` but serverless doesn't pick them up.

One of the lambda code is:

```
'use strict';

const { awsRequest, wait } = require('../utils');
const { getEnvironment, handlerWrapper } = require('../utils');

async function handler(event, context) {
  if (event.RequestType === 'Create') {
    return create(event, context);
  } else if (event.RequestType === 'Update') {
    return update(event, context);
  } else if (event.RequestType === 'Delete') {
    return remove(event, context);
  }
  throw new Error(`Unhandled RequestType ${event.RequestType}`);
}

async function create(event, context) {
  const { RoleArn } = event.ResourceProperties;
  const { Partition: partition, AccountId: accountId, Region: region } = getEnvironment(context);

  const assignedRoleArn = (
    await awsRequest({ name: 'APIGateway', params: { region } }, 'getAccount')
  ).cloudwatchRoleArn;

  let roleArn = `arn:${partition}:iam::${accountId}:role/serverlessApiGatewayCloudWatchRole`;
  if (RoleArn) {
    // if there's a roleArn in the Resource Properties, just re-use it here
    roleArn = RoleArn;
  } else {
    // Create an own API Gateway role if the roleArn was not set via Resource Properties
    const apiGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogsPolicyArn = `arn:${partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs`;

    const roleName = roleArn.slice(roleArn.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    const attachedPolicies = await (async () => {
      try {
        return (await awsRequest('IAM', 'listAttachedRolePolicies', { RoleName: roleName }))
          .AttachedPolicies;
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 'NoSuchEntity') {
          // Role doesn't exist yet, create;
          await awsRequest('IAM', 'createRole', {
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument: JSON.stringify({
              Version: '2012-10-17',
              Statement: [
                {
                  Effect: 'Allow',
                  Principal: {
                    Service: ['apigateway.amazonaws.com'],
                  },
                  Action: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
                },
              ],
            }),
            Path: '/',
            RoleName: roleName,
          });
          return [];
        }
        throw error;
      }
    })();

    if (
      !attachedPolicies.some(
        (policy) => policy.PolicyArn === apiGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogsPolicyArn
      )
    ) {
      await awsRequest('IAM', 'attachRolePolicy', {
        PolicyArn: apiGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogsPolicyArn,
        RoleName: roleName,
      });
    }
  }

  // there's nothing to do if the role is the same
  if (roleArn === assignedRoleArn) return null;

  const updateAccount = async (counter = 1) => {
    try {
      await awsRequest({ name: 'APIGateway', params: { region } }, 'updateAccount', {
        patchOperations: [
          {
            op: 'replace',
            path: '/cloudwatchRoleArn',
            value: roleArn,
          },
        ],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (counter < 10) {
        // Observed fails with errors marked as non-retryable. Still they're outcome of
        // temporary state where just created AWS role is not being ready for use (yet)
        await wait(10000);
        return updateAccount(++counter);
      }
      throw error;
    }
    return null;
  };

  return updateAccount();
}

function update() {
  // No actions
}

function remove() {
  // No actions
}

module.exports = {
  handler: handlerWrapper(handler, 'CustomResourceApiGatewayAccountCloudWatchRole'),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> And how to attach VPC on those lambdas?

You can apply VPC on 2 levels:

- `provider.vpc`: apply VPC configuration to all functions in your service
- `functions.<LambdaName>.vpc`: add VPC configuration to a specific function

Documentation:

- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#vpc-configuration

Pseudo-code:

```yaml
# add VPC configuration to a specific function
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - securityGroupId1
        - securityGroupId2
      subnetIds:
        - subnetId1
        - subnetId2

# apply VPC configuration to all functions in your service  
provider:
  name: aws
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - securityGroupId1
      - securityGroupId2
    subnetIds:
      - subnetId1
      - subnetId2
```

> What I am looking for is how to add tags on those auto generated lambda

You have 3 level of tags in Serverless Framework, and they are passed to CloudFormation.

- `provider.tags`: CloudFormation tags to apply to APIs and functions
- `provider.stackTags`: CloudFormation tags to apply to the stack and all supported resources. Tags are applied to all its children's, including auto-generated resources
- `functions.<LambdaName>.tags`: Function specific tags

Documentation:

- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/#general-settings
- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#tags

Pseudo-code:

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  tags: # CloudFormation tags to apply to APIs and functions
    key: value
  stackTags: # CloudFormation tags to apply to the stack and all 
    key: value

    
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    tags: # Function specific tags
      key: value
```

**Important:** In both cases, VPC or Tags configuration, the inheritance and overwrites are at play. You can define a value in a higher level (`provider.vpc`) and overwrite it in the resource level (`functions.<LambdaName>.vpc`)

Comment: it works only for the function I created. But my issue is how to tag the functions created by serverless automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "the functions created by serverless automatically?". For example, when you define "functions.<SomeName>" it automatically creates a lambda function for you. You don't need to define "AWS::Lambda::Function" resource. Perhaps there's some confusion here. The "provider.stackTags" will propagate tags to all resource types. If you are creating resources outside Serverless Framework scope, tag them manually.

Comment: The function is not defined in `functions`. When you deploy a apigateway and a lambda, there is a lambda with a random name deployed by serverless which is used to update the role for your apigateway to call your lambda. Just like the code in my post which is not written by me.

Comment: We'll need a more concrete example from you. A "random lambda" can be generated by a plugin or external process. There's no such thing as a "random lambda" when using Serverless Framework-only definitions (no plugins). Start a new project with "sls" CLI and you will see. You could try to identify the resource stack via "aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --physical-resource-id <arn>" to see from where this resources is coming from.

Comment: I have updated the post to give an example how this lambda is created